# Restricting Internet Access in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, group-policy

On a Windows 7 Professional laptop, not on a domain, what's the best way to restrict access to the internet (and preferably network) to Administrator users only?

I don't want to simply set a bogus network address, or proxy.  That seems far too dirty somehow.

Comment: OK, is the use case "restrict human users" or "restrict accounts that are used to run a service?"

Comment: Human users.  I haven't begun to consider Service Accounts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

802.1 and/or NAC/NAP, if your switches and/or servers support it. By default, the laptop would only be in a subnet with no gateway. Then, if certain users can present creds to the auth system, they could be put in a non-quarantined network.

I realize that this isn't "local policy" as such, but it'll work and it's even enterprise-y (centrally managed, fine-grained, etc).

Comment: This is indeed promising.

Answer (score 5):

I think that your 2nd paragraph is the only way since only admins can change IPs and enable/disable NICs... Just disable all the NICs.

Comment: I'm just irritated by windows and the insanity of it all..  Ever tried to get WPA2-Enterprise working with a Cisco AP541 something, and the *cheapest* lenovo laptop ever.

Comment: My reputation's pretty much all linux and so on.

Comment: well my reputation is pretty much windows.  The quickest and most effective way to restrict internet access (and preferably also network as you said) is to disable the NICs in Control Panel > Network and Sharing Center > Manage Network Connections.  Only admins can enable them.

Comment: @August Higher Rep = More Abrasive Comments. ;)

Comment: Ok I deleted my "abrasive" comment now that we've straightened everything out.  No harm - just trying to keep this a family show for the kids.  @Tom - yes Lenovos are crap pretty much ever since IBM sold their laptop division to them.  I'd consider them for home use only.

Comment: August, if  you edit your answer to say "Use Parental Controls", I'll accept it, as that's basically what i'm doing, and it seems to work ;)

Comment: sorry that never even occurred to me.  If that works for you then go for it I guess. If that's what you're doing then I'd say just make your own answer and accept it since nobody else came up with the solution you are using.

Answer (score -1):

Just a suggestion where to look at: If you can restrict who can create a socket and bind it to a certain type of port, which might or might not be possible by policy, you will have a setup that will restrict an one user WHILE the other user can use the network.

Comment: That's not really something that Windows does or can do.

Comment: This should've been a Question comment.

Comment: Tom - no, I'm replying to rackandboneman. Windows has no ACL structure to allow/disallow users to open certain ports, so it's a bad answer. There's some hacked-up ways in Windows to get a close answer for the question, but rack's answer is not something that can be done.

Comment: To clarify: I am sometimes too tempted to give hints on what layer of an OS I would look for an answer. And "where ports are bound" would be the one of the likely candidates.

Comment: @rackandboneman - sure, if Windows had such a facility, that would be a great way to do it. It doesn't; I don't think the hooks are even there for 3rd-party software to do it. I honestly don't think there are even any Unices that do that. Can you give any examples of where you've seen this or something like it? I'm very curious.

Answer (score -2):

If you create a domain, even with only the single computer, then Active Directory could selectively disable certain programs, for certain users on said domain.  Otherwise, i suppose you could change the permissions of internet explorer to require administrative access (vvia the properties -> security tab)

Comment: That won't restrict access to the Internet, though. There are plenty of browsers that can install/run without admin rights.

Comment: only if they bring it in on a flash drive...

Comment: If you try and block internet access to a user that wants it, that's the first thing that they're going to do.

Comment: you could always put a company policy into place.

Answer (score -2):

I'm pretty sure that you can restrict internet through local group policy.

Comment: Why the -2?  Its a legit and correct answer.